# Compilando sass mediante npm

Tags: css, npm, sass

Estoy tratando de compilar sass mediante npm, ya lo registre en el package.json pero cuando le doy a correr me sale el sisguiente error:

```
"Exercises\project-tracking-intro-component-master\node_modules\.bin\" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Documents\Programming\node-sass\bin\node-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Asi esta registrado en el json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/main.css"
  },
}
```

No se si fui muy claro es mi primera vez en stack xd

Comment: hola!, que version de node tienes?, lo instalaste con "npm i node-sass"?

Comment: v16.14.0. Si si lo instale asi